# Thrusters in space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rocket-science

Suppose we propel ourself using thrusters in space. If we have two thrusters pushing against each other like this:

[image]

Nothing will happen. We can imagine the "strain" on the vehicle chassis; the forces are not working. All the thruster's fuel is wasted.

Now, if we have two thrusters like that:

[image]

The resulting force intensity is $\sqrt{2}$, which is less than $2$, the sum of forces provided by thrusters. Does it mean, like on the previous example, that some fuel is wasted ?

Consequently, does it mean that ideally we would like to orient the thrusters toward the direction we want to push ?

Answer (score 0):

> Consequently, does it mean that ideally we would like to orient the thrusters toward the direction we want to push ?

Assuming a spherical cow (which is a big assumption), your conclusion is correct because there are vector components of the the two thrusters that oppose each other and cancel out.

In practice, you need to consider the weight, complexity, and cost of mechanisms to-orient thrusters and that of two smaller thrusters versus one larger thruster.

Comment: I understand thanks! I think another parameter that I don't really know about is how much you want to save your propellant. Moreover, if you don't have any mechanism to orient your thrusters, I feel like you need plenty of them (at least 7 since it is a 6D simplex), to control forces+moments am I right? Do you know what choices are made in practice?

Comment: @Maximus I don't, but I'm sure someone on the Space Exploration or Engineering Stack Exchange does because that's no longer a Physics SE question.